# ¿How can I store data in an array after each value of variable changes in python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have to save the totals that are defined in the conditional, so as not to have to manually place the names of each city, start a variable x that stores the value of the ciudad[i] and I should go through this list one by one and save the totals in another list but I could not and would like to know what to do.I am doing this in python 3x with pandas.

```py
ciudad=['ARMENIA', 'BARRANQUILLA', 'BOGOTA', 'BUCARAMANGA', 'BUENAVENTURA', 'CALI', 'CARTAGENA', 'CUCUTA', 'FLORENCIA', 'IPIALES', 'MANIZALES', 'MEDELLIN', 'MONTERIA', 'NEIVA', 'PASTO', 'PEREIRA', 'POPAYAN', 'RIOHACHA', 'SAN ANDRES', 'SANTA MARTA', 'SINCELEJO', 'TUNJA', 'VALLEDUPAR', 'VILLAVICENCIO']
Cuenta=0
for i in range(len(Sucursal)):
    if i < len(ciudad):
        x=ciudad[i]
        #print(x)
    if(data.loc[i,"CIUDAD"]==x) and (data.loc[i,"Vida Util Restante(per)"]==0):  
        Cuenta+=1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your question to improve it, like adding a tag for programming language.

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Comment: Excuse me, you are absolutely right. I am going to take your advice and take the tour. I am new to this and I am exploring what is at hand to learn and over time contribute with what I have learned, I hope I could be part of a team where they can welcome me as a learner and solve all the knowledge gaps in programming from practice.

Comment: `name 'Sucursal' is not defined`, example output also missing